# Access list of map values in dart?

Tags: dart

I have this list of  map , how to access "answers" values for each index from this map?

```
var questions = [
    {
      "question": "Whats your favourite color?",
      "answers": ["Red", "Green", "Yellow"]
    },
    {
      "question": "Whats your favourite animal?",
      "answers": ["Tiger", "Elephant", "Unicorn"]
    },
    {
      "question": "Whats your favourite game?",
      "answers": ["Tiger", "Elephant", "Unicorn"]
    }
  ];
```

Comment: ```questions.forEach((element) => print(element['answers']));```

Comment: `(_questions[_index++]["answers"] as List<String>)[i++]`

Comment: (questions[_quizIndex]["answer"] as List<String>)
                  .map((answer) => print( answer))
                  .toList()

Answer (score 1):

It's just a List of Objects. You can simply access with this:

```
questions.forEach((element) {
  print(element['answers']);
});
```

And to print answers:

```
questions.forEach((element) {
  var answers = element['answers'];
  answers.forEach((answer) {
    print(answer);
  });
});
```

Comment: Just a tip of the day. You can just write `answers.forEach(print)` and it will automatically call the `print` method for each element.

Comment: Getting this error on second code-   The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'

Comment: Try `var answers = element['answers'] as List;`. The problem is the compiler cannot guess what type `element['answers']` returns.